# Using %T>% to complete a pipeline for an object

Tags: r, r-markdown

So far I have the result stored into the object result2.
The goal of the pipe is to take this filtered dataset,
THEN extract body_size and brain volume data,
THEN plot a scatterplot of body size and brain volume
THEN return a summary

I am trying to accomplish this by using the pipe operators to complete this pipeline, but I am doing something wrong.

```
result2<-fish %>%
  filter(body_size>0) %>%
  extract(body_size, brain_volume) %T>%
  plot() %>%
  summary()
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since the output of `plot` won't be used in `summary`. You will need to break this chain of pipes up.

Answer (score 1):

As advised by LMc, I think you will need to call your plot and summary separately. Pasting your error message(if you get one) could help to see where your issue is exactly.

Even when you run your code in one chunk, the summary appears to get executed after the plot is rendered and isn't related, so I think it's okay.

```
 result2<-fish %>%
 filter(body_size>0) %>%
 extract(body_size, brain_volume) %T>%
 plot()
```

and

```
 result2 %>% 
 summary()
```

Comment: You can call both the plot and summary. OP is using the pipe `%T>%` AND NOT `%>%`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the pipe but rather the `extract` function. It seems that your data especially the `body_size` column is already numeric and thats why you could `filter` out those that are greater than 0. So what exactly are you trying to `extract` from a numeric vector? Why do you have extract? Probably you meant `select` since you want to plot hence you need two variables:

Your code should be:

```
result2 <- fish %>%
  filter(body_size>0) %>%
  select(body_size, brain_volume) %T>%
  plot() %>%
  summary()
```